# jQuery .get function sending request multiple times

Tags: jquery, click

I have the following code in my head area:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#idNameHere").click(function() {
        var title = $("#threadTitle").val();
        var category = $("#category").val();
        var message = CKEDITOR.instances['message'].getData();

        errors = new Array();
        if (title == "")
            errors.push("\n\t- You must enter a title.");
        if (category == "")
            errors.push("\n\t- You must select a category.");
        if (message == "")
            errors.push("\n\t- You must enter a message.");

        if (errors.length > 0)
        {
            var errorString = "Please fix the following errors and try again:";
            for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++)
                errorString = errorString + errors[i];

            alert(errorString);
        }
        else
        {
            $.get("./ajax/createThread.php", { title: title, category:category, message: message }, function(data) {
                if (!isNaN(data))
                    window.location='./viewThread.php?tid='+data;
                else
                    alert(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Sometimes (but not always) it sends the request multiple times - so I end up with thread objects being inserted into my database in multiples.

From what I've read, it's because the click function is within the $(function() {}); area - However, if i take the click function out of that area, the click event isn't caught and the code isn't run at all.

How can I get the click function to register, and ONLY run once?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: most likely it's happening more than once because someone is clicking said button more than once. I would solve this server-side, having the server code detect if said record already exists and doing nothing in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want the $.get to only happen once, then you need to disable the button after it is run.

so you have to add this line; `$("#idNameHere").attr("disabled", "disabled")` to disable the button.

and then this `$("#idNameHere").removeAttr("disabled");` to enable it, in case there's an error

**Kevin B; PS:**
or preferably .prop("disabled",true)
and .prop("disabled", false)
 I'm guessing this is for older browser versions and IE

like this;

```
 $("#idNameHere").click(function() {
        $("#idNameHere").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var title = $("#threadTitle").val();
        var category = $("#category").val();
        var message = CKEDITOR.instances['message'].getData();

        errors = new Array();
        if (title == "")
            errors.push("\n\t- You must enter a title.");
        if (category == "")
            errors.push("\n\t- You must select a category.");
        if (message == "")
            errors.push("\n\t- You must enter a message.");

        if (errors.length > 0)
        {
            var errorString = "Please fix the following errors and try again:";
                for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++)
                    errorString = errorString + errors[i];

            alert(errorString);

            //re-enable the button
            $("#idNameHere").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else
        {
            $.get("./ajax/createThread.php", { title: title, category:category, message: message }, function(data) {
                if (!isNaN(data)){
                    window.location='./viewThread.php?tid='+data;
                }else{
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: or preferably `.prop("disabled",true)`

Comment: much more elegant way to achieve the same thing I said, very nice!

Comment: Why disable it at the start and then re-enabled it, instead of just disabling it before sending the ajax?

Comment: because I'm guessing he's doing some client side validation in there (I didn't really read all the code), and if the data is invalid, he will not send the get request, therefore when the user corrects their erroneous input, the user can click and try again. ie. we only want to keep the button disabled if the get request actually happens

Comment: I'll throw on the disable code... Once the information is submitted, the user should be redirected to the "view" page - so there won't ever be a need to submit the info twice... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I often create a global variable and set it to true. You make it part of the condition and set it to flase after you run your function, you then have your function return the global variable to true once it get's the data (if you want to be able to run the function again).